# FileOutputStream constructor is looking for file object in temp folder of tomcat instead of heap

Tags: java, tomcat

In my program I am creating a file class object with a file name. After that to write into it I am creating a `FileOutputStream` object with the above file object.

```
File file = new File("mod.properties");
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

When it is running in the tomcat server, it is looking for the 'file' object in temp folder. Instead of the heap. And it is not happening in every tomcat server, but in few of them.

> [Unable to fetch model from folder path 
>   /opt/tomcat/temp/1501748741522-0][STACK][java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   mod.properties (No such file or directory)    at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method) at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)  at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:213)    at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:162)    at

Comment: So what's the difference between the few tomcat servers that have the error and the others who don't?

Comment: I tried to find some. But couldn't find any. Tomcat version, configuration, heap size are exactly same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the java.io.File javadoc:
" An absolute pathname is complete in that no other information is required in order to locate the file that it denotes. A relative pathname, in contrast, must be interpreted in terms of information taken from some other pathname. By default the classes in the java.io package always resolve relative pathnames against the current user directory. This directory is named by the system property user.dir, and is typically the directory in which the Java virtual machine was invoked."

You are setting a relative pathname when constructing File, so here you have your answer: those instances have different properties/settings.

Comment: What i interpret from your answer, if i check the System.getProperty("user.dir") before the above piece of code executes, i will find it to be the "temp" directory. And since i have created a file with no absolute path, it is creating as well as looking for the file in "user.dir" which is temp. Please confirm if my understanding with "creating and looking" is correct or not. Or it is creating in heap and looking in "user.dir".

Comment: yes, and i guess that if you check that user.dir property on each of your tomcat servers, you would see it has different values. that would be the reason for having different behaviour for that matter.